# Return 1 if day is in month

Tags: sql-server, calendar

I made a calender in SQL
The field “is_mtd_alles” returns 1 in the calendar on the days of the month that are in the current month number up to and including today.
That is correct in the table above, only the date 1-1-2020 is missing.

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8TUy.png)

This the code that decides whether it's 0 or 1:

```
`[is_mtd_all]  AS (case when datepart(dayofyear,[Date])<=datepart(dayofyear,getdate()) AND datepart(month,[Date])=datepart(month,getdate()) then (1) else (0) end),`
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code uses several product specific functions.)

Comment: Microsft SQL Server

Comment: Just to confirm, if you run a query like `select * from CalendarTable where [Date] = '2020-01-01'`, you do get a result back, right? Like, this date isn't just missing from your calendar table for some reason?

Comment: Yes, 2020 is in the table.

Comment: The "current month" has 2 attributes that need to be compared to any other date - the year and the month. You don't check the year at all. Is that supposed to be part of your logic? Should the dates Sept 1 2020 and Sept 1 2021 yield 1 or 0 for your case expression? And please do not post images - especially tiny, low-resolution ones.

Answer (score 0):

I created a table called `date_calendar` which has a `datetime` field called `calendar_date` and populated it with every date from 2020 to 2050.

The following query then performed as I believe you are requesting:

```
select
    calendar_date,
    case 
        when datepart(day,calendar_date) <= datepart(day,getdate()) 
            and datepart(month,calendar_date) = datepart(month,getdate())
        then 1 else 0
    end as is_mtd_alles
from date_calendar
```

I think the issue with your code is it uses `dayofyear` instead of `day` and 2020 was a leap year, so had a different number of days.

If this doesn't work on your table, we'll probably need to see the table schema and sample data with expected results to be able to help you further.